# Inference with a model trained with tf.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have trained a model using the `tf.data.Dataset` API, so my training code looks something like this

```
with graph.as_default():
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_path)
    dataset = dataset.map(scale_features, num_parallel_calls=n_workers)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)
    dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes={...})
    handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
    iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle,
                                                   train_dataset.output_types,
                                                   train_dataset.output_shapes)
    batch = iterator.get_next()
    ... 
    # Model code
    ...
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    train_handle = sess.run(iterator.string_handle())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={handle: train_handle})
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
               break
```

Now after the model is trained I want to infer on examples that are not in the datasets and I am not sure how to go about doing it.

Just to be clear, I know how to use another dataset, for example I just pass a handle to my test set upon testing.

The question is about given the scaling scheme and the fact that the network expects a handle, if I want to make a prediction to a new example which is not written to a TFRecord, how would I go about doing that?

If I'd modify the `batch` I'd be responsible for the scaling beforehand which is something I would like to avoid if possible.

So how should I infer single examples from a model traiend the `tf.data.Dataset` way?
(This is not for production purposes it is for evaluating what will happen if I change specific features)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually there is a tensor name called "IteratorGetNext:0" in the graph
 when you use dataset api, so you can using following way to directly set 
 input:

```
#get a tensor from a graph 
input tensor : input = graph.get_tensor_by_name("IteratorGetNext:0")
# difine the target tensor you want evaluate for your prediction
prediction tensor: predictions=...
# finally call session to run 
then sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={input: np.asanyarray(images), ...})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: you should note  that `feed_dict` is not `tensorflow` recommendation for production system. But it does simplify thing.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav  thanks for your suggestion!   i have update the answer!

Comment: @oak I am looking for a solution other than using feed_dict? Do you have any? Or this is the only way. Is the purpose of "TF recommendation" to do the following evil: "optimize the code before actually making it runs".

Comment: @ArtificiallyIntelligence we are using TensorRT for inference in production. Tensorflow used to have queue. But its deprecated .I think that a direction for replacing `feed_dict` will be checking tf.data